# Writing consistent data to file in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to write a library which logs data to a file. Unfortunately, my system suffers from unexpected reboots and power loss.
Does Linux write operation to a file guaranties that my file will always contain consistent data? Does it guarantee "all or nothing"?

If so, is there a limitation on the size of the data being written?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you mount the file system you can specify one of the below options. It seems like the third one suits my requirements.
This is what I found at 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/ext3.txt

### Data Mode

There are 3 different data modes:

- writeback mode
  In data=writeback mode, ext3 does not journal data at all.  This mode provides
  a similar level of journaling as that of XFS, JFS, and ReiserFS in its default
  mode - metadata journaling.  A crash+recovery can cause incorrect data to
  appear in files which were written shortly before the crash.  This mode will
  typically provide the best ext3 performance.
- ordered mode
  In data=ordered mode, ext3 only officially journals metadata, but it logically
  groups metadata and data blocks into a single unit called a transaction.  When
  it's time to write the new metadata out to disk, the associated data blocks
  are written first.  In general, this mode performs slightly slower than
  writeback but significantly faster than journal mode.
- journal mode
  data=journal mode provides full data and metadata journaling.  All new data is
  written to the journal first, and then to its final location.
  In the event of a crash, the journal can be replayed, bringing both data and
  metadata into a consistent state.  This mode is the slowest except when data
  needs to be read from and written to disk at the same time where it
  outperforms all other modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can never predict where a physical write operations stops on a power outage. Even if you use `journaling` features of some filesystems. Note that the journal needs to get written too.

Comment: You may also want to close the file descriptor after each flush in the event that a power loss occurs before the next write. I don't know what affect a crash with an open descriptor will have after a flush, but if it were me, I'd `open -> write -> flush -> close` for each write operation in this instance.

Comment: I asked whether it is consistent, not persistent.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `consistent`?

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble understanding. Yes it will write what your tell it to if that is your questions..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is too much overhead, also flush would be enough.

Comment: That's good information - thanks. I've never considered the circumstance.

Comment: Consistency means "all or nothing". If I write some buffer and during the operation the power is lost. Is it possible for me to find only part of the buffer written? Will I find garbage there?

Comment: @user1543532 If you just use `write` and not `flush` propably all data will get lost. Even if the kernel would write immediately without need of flush, the hardware allows only little amount of data to get written at a time. Or do you expect to write 10TB at a time, consistently?

Comment: I don't mind data getting loss, I just want to make sure my file always contains valid data. I plan to write about 10KB at a time. If there is a limitation on the size I want to know what it is.

Comment: He's asking if you write `"hello"` is it possible that the file will only contain `"hell"` in the event someone yanks out the power cable. He doesn't care if nothing is written. He doesn't care if "hello" is written. But he doesn't want to see "hell" when he writes "hello".

Comment: @slebetman Of course "hell" ( `:)` ) will being possible. But it really depends. You can never say where a physical write operations stops on a power outage. Also you can't say if `hell` is at the outer boundary of (the last) network package sent to a network storage before being offline....

Comment: @hek2mgl: Then that's the answer to the question. Not the answer you posted above.

Comment: The answer is that it depends how you mount the file system. If you mount it with "data=journal" then "hell" is not possible.

Comment: You expect too much from that. What if the power outage occurs during the write to the journal?

Comment: Then the write cannot be replayed, and the data will not be written to the file.

Comment: Journals have limited size and need to get written from time to time. What if `hell` is located at the border of such a limit? (Btw, I really appreciate this discussion!)

Comment: The journal is a circular log. Once a transaction has been committed, it is marked as free in the log. I assume that if a new transaction wants to start and the journal is full, then it is pended.